# Adding new label/reference command pairs to RefTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, labels, emacs, reftex

I would like to add the label commands `\pflabel` and `\pflonglabel`, as well as their corresponding reference command `\pfref` to RefTeX. I would like them to work like `\label`/`\ref` do by default, but be additional options.

Would someone know how I might do this?

Comment: Are you also using AUCTeX?

Comment: Yes, I am using AUCTeX!

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using AUCTeX as well, I suggest you put your TeX macros inside a package, e.g. `pflabel.sty`, which can look like this:

```
\ProvidesPackage{pflabel}
  [2019/09/08 v1.0 Support for pflabel's]
\let\pflabel\label
\let\pflonglabel\label
\let\pfref\ref
\endinput
```

Save this file in a directory where LaTeX can find it.

Next, you need to write the corresponding support file `pflabel.el` for AUCTeX and RefTeX which can look like this:

```el
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "pflabel"
 (lambda ()

   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("pflabel"     TeX-arg-define-label)
    '("pflonglabel" TeX-arg-define-label)
    '("pfref"       TeX-arg-ref))

   ;; Tell AUCTeX about the macros
   (TeX-auto-add-regexp
    '("\\\\pf\\(?:long\\)?label{\\([^\n\r%\\{}]+\\)}" 1 LaTeX-auto-label))

   ;; Check if reftex-vars.el is loaded:
   (when (featurep 'reftex-vars)
     (make-local-variable 'reftex-label-alist)
     (make-local-variable 'reftex-label-regexps)
     (make-local-variable 'reftex-ref-style-alist)
     (dolist (mac '("pflabel" "pflonglabel"))
       (add-to-list 'reftex-label-alist
                    `(,(concat "\\" mac "{*}") nil nil nil nil)
                    t)
       (add-to-list 'reftex-label-regexps
                    (concat "\\\\" mac "{\\(?1:[^\n\r%\\{}]+\\)}")
                    t)
       (unless (string-match-p
                "\\<pflabel\\>"
                (mapconcat #'identity reftex-label-regexps "\\|"))
         (reftex-compile-variables)))

     ;; Add a new reference style
     (add-to-list 'reftex-ref-style-alist
                  '("PFlabel" "pflabel"
                    (("\\pfref" ?P)))
                  t)

     ;; And activate it
     (and LaTeX-reftex-ref-style-auto-activate
          (fboundp 'reftex-ref-style-activate)
          (reftex-ref-style-activate "PFlabel")))

   ;; Fontification
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
              (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("pflabel"     "{")
                                ("pflonglabel" "{")
                                ("pfref"       "{"))
                              'reference)))
 LaTeX-dialect)

;;; pflabel.el ends here
```

Customize the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory of your choice, e.g.:

```el
(setq TeX-style-private (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/auctex-styles"))
```

And save `pflabel.el` in that directory.  Make sure you have the following line in your init file:

```el
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

and this line in your `.tex` file.

```
\usepackage{pflabel}
```

Now restart Emacs and load your `.tex` file.

Comment: Wow, thank you!! I will try this as soon as I can!

Comment: Thanks again! And, my apologies for taking so long to reply. I tried your solution, but received an error: ERROR: Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete. --- TeX said --- <to be read again> \par l.3069 --- HELP --- A blank line occurred in a command argument that shouldn't contain one. You probably forgot the right brace at the end of an argument.

Comment: Just to be sure, I already have pflabel, pflonglabel, and pfref commands in my tex file that work and are independent from \label/\ref. I would like to add them to RefTeX so that it makes custom tags, etc., like it does for \label/\ref. What makes it necessary to define \pflabel, etc. as \label, \ref in the package?

Comment: @AnthonyPulido - `\usepackage{pflabel}` is only needed to give AUCTeX the hint that it should load `pflabel.el`.  You can move your LaTeX code in a .sty file, but you don't have to.  You can fool AUCTeX by putting this in your preamble: `\iffalse \usepackage{pflabel} \fi`.  IMO, the lisp code above should be in an AUCTeX style file and loaded upon request.  Otherwise, you have to pollute your init file with it and that's more effort.

Comment: I see, that's what the package is for. Thank you! Does it make a difference that I am also using `\label` / `\ref` in the tex file?

Comment: @AnthonyPulido - Do you mean from AUCTeX/RefTeX POV? No, not that I'm aware of.  AUCTeX/RefTeX can also handle macros like `\eqref`, `\cref` etc.